# Should I use XFS or EXT4 for music storage drive?

Tags: filesystems, ssd

I have a 1TB SSD which sole purpose will be to store music in FLAC format. A FLAC file is about 20-30MB in size and there will be thousands of them on the drive.

At a later time I would like to add Hi-Res Audio Flacs as well and those size is even bigger, at around 50-100MB per file.

The ext4 seems to be the standard fs on most Linux systems but I checked the information available about XFS and I only read good things about it. Even though, I'm not sure if XFS would be okay in my case and how well XFS is supported across Linux distributions. Any suggestion is appreciated.

As a disadvantage it is often mentioned that journaling cannot be disabled on XFS that can cause additional wear on SSDs. Does journaling disables itself automatically on ext4 at all? Because I don't remember having the need to disable it and probably I wouldn't want to disable it.

Comment: Journaling is needed to avoid the corruption of the file system if the system halt (kernel panic, power shortage…). It will typically double the number of write of metadata, but the data are not journaled by the system (but application like database server including sqlite journalise at their level). Metadata are a tiny part of the file system, especially with music files, then I won’t try to disable it. You may try to mount the file system with noatime and avoid the access time to be updated (this writes the SSD even if your use is read-only).

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer: Yes, but journaling only makes a difference when the filesystem is being written to, and as I understand it that will rarely be the case here. I have had a couple of music disc myself (one at a time, replacing it when it got old) consider FAT too so it can be used on a windows machine or car stereo too.

Comment: Yes, writting will be rarely the case. Once the music is transferred to the drive I will only use the drive for reading.

Comment: XFS has been around for a long time so it should be supported by almost every Linux distro. Filesystem choice is a matter of opinion, regular users won't know or notice the difference.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak Crucial. Does that matter for the fs?

Comment: @Henrik supports the community : I think we agree, with its usage, journaling doesn’t hurt when writing and is not ever used when reading. No need to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XFS is supported across Linux distributions

It's supported by most distros, and all mainstream ones (Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch)

> I only read good things about it

It cannot be shrunk - that's the biggest concern.

> journaling cannot be disabled on XFS that can cause additional wear on SSDs

Modern SSDs have enough storage to accommodate journalling. Besides you're talking about storing relatively big files, relatively rarely. Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome and other applications create a ton more tear and wear by default.

> Does journaling disables itself automatically on ext4 at all?

No, it must be disabled manually or you can create a partition without a journal from the get go. `mkfs.ext4 -O ^has_journal` has got you covered.